# COTURN using too much CPU !!. Is this normal?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, turn, video-conferencing, coturn

Thank you all,

I have a video conference project developed using **WebRTC API** and I build my own TURN server using open source COTURN. According to my reads turn and stun servers are not cpu or memory intensive servers, but my turn server is using over **90%** cpu of **8 core** ubuntu server with only **100 clients**. Up to now I have managed to serve video conference service but now I am about to serve 75000 clients and I am afraid, with these numbers I am not able to manage it.

Here is my TURN server configuration:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Is there any case that coturn(or any turn server) uses that much CPU?

Answer (score 3):

Are the 100 clients connected to each other? Like a super conference?

In this case, it makes sense that the load is so big.

Following any normal guide for implementing WebRTC conferences, you create a what's called [mesh topology](https://www.link-labs.com/blog/what-is-mesh-topology), where every connection is replicated for each other client present.

Let's give an example for your case. When you join the call and there are already 99 people present, your video (and audio) is being sent individually for each client 99 times.
So your configuration is creating 100*99/2=4950 connections for 100 people!

I recommend checking out the [different topologies](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-network-topology/) you can implement and see if one fits your idea and has less load impact.

You might also be thinking that 4950 connections are not so many still, but bear in mind that WebRTC transmits even when there is no audio or video, so it's 4950 connections having data flowing at the same time.

As a famous example, Discord is able to handle an extreme amount of concurrent connections because they optimize every little thing in each connection. One of those optimizations is that they stop transmitting data when there's no media flowing, which you can definitely implement (requires a bit more knowledge on WebRTC, but not that hard).

I suggest delving more deeply into WebRTC if this is the path you're choosing since your case is one that requires more knowledge.

Comment: I'm afraid the system with 100 clients connected to each other by WebRTC Mesh, sending video/audio won't even start.